# Rails/Memcached: caching tree-like structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I'm using memcached to store my heavier queries, but have hit a roadblock when attempting to cache a sitemap of Page models.

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree
end
```

Example:

```
page
  -- child_page1
    -- subchild_page1
    -- subchild_page2
```

I'm at a loss on how I can store this with Memcached.  Any suggestions would go a long way!

```
Rails.cache.fetch("foo") do
  # not sure how to store the pages.  perhaps as a hash?
end
```

Comment: looks like a map reduce problem to me

Comment: you map `page->child-Page1`; `child_page1->{subchild page1, subchild page2}`; then you use map reduce to go deeper into the tree. Use page and/or child-page1 as keys to traverse the tree/graph: `reduce(child-page1)` returns the entire list of subchildren. `reduce(page)` returns chld-page1